# Subsets - Problem with understanding

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have two sets $A=\{2\}$ and $B=\{2\}$, can I say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and vice versa? I am coding in event $B$ and I need to check that $A \nsubseteq B$

Comment: They look like the same set to me; care to explain your notation?

Comment: what does $\left\{2\right]$ mean? never seen this notation. if it's a typo then obviously $A=B$.

Comment: Ye they are the same set but I am wondering can I call A a subset of B

Comment: yes. and the other way around. no "proper" subset though.

Comment: @user1552404 yes; for sets, "equals" implies "is a subset of." So A ⊈ B is false.

Comment: A = {2} donates that A consists of the set 2, anything inside the brackets belongs to the set

Answer (score 1):

Every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. Therefore $A\subseteq B$.  And every element of $B$ is an element of $A$, so $B\subseteq A$.

The subset relation is a weak inequality, like "less than or equals".  That's why many of us prefer to avoid the symbol "$\subset$", and use "$\subseteq$" instead - both symbols have the same meaning, but the first can be a little confusing.

---

It's also worth noting that $\subseteq $ is a partial ordering relationship:

1. Reflexivity holds because $A\subseteq A$.
2. Transitivity holds since if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, then $A\subseteq C$.
3. And antisymmetry holds since if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, it must be the case that $A=B$.

Furthermore, in many universes (power sets for example), we get a lattice structure: The *join* (least upper bound) of $A$ and $B$ is just $A\cup B$, and the *meet* (greatest lower bound) is $A\cap B$. It is not for nothing that the symbols usually used for lattice operations ($\leq,\vee,\wedge$) so closely echo those used for set operations ($\subseteq,\cup,\cap$).